# Create type that is union of function results

Tags: typescript, redux

I have a some of functions and I need the union type of the functions result types.

#### Example

*Input function types:*

```
type InputType1 = () => {type: "INCREASE"}
type InputType2 = () => {type: "ADD", by: number}
```

Output type:

```
type ResultType = {type: "INCREASE"} | {type: "ADD", by: number}
```

---

#### Current

The current code I have is very verbose but looks like this:

```
function returntypeof<RT>(expression: (...param: any[]) => RT): RT {
  return {} as RT;
}

const AllTypes = {
  1: returntypeof(InputType1),
  2: returntypeof(InputType2),
};

type ResultType = typeof AllTypes[keyof typeof AllTypes];
```

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453
Currently, you have to rely on overloads

Comment: @unional What would that look like? :)

Answer (score 1):

Before variadic is available (and figured out how to do this), for now you can try this:

```
function foo<T1, T2>(x1: T1, x2?: T2): T1 & T2 {
  return {} as T1 & T2; 
}

let y = foo({ a: 1 })
let x = foo({ a: 1 }, { b: 'b' })
```